# ¿Cómo realizar en JS una función que reciba un objeto?

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

¿Cómo puedo crear una función que reciba un objeto ya definido y retorne la suma de horas de trabajo de cada una de las actividades de la primera asignatura - “Realidad Virtual”. Pues al llamar la función con la instrucción: `console.log(horasTotales(proyectos))`, en la consola se escribirá **75.**

```
let proyectos = {
  numero_Proyectos : 2,
  trabajos : [
    {
    nombre_asignatura1: "Realidad Virtual",
    creditos: 12,
    dificultad: "media",
    numero_Actividades: 3,
    actividades: [
      {
      nombre_actividad1: "Esperiencias Artísticas en RV",
      horasdetrabajo: 20,
      iniciodeltrabajo: "09/9/24"
      },
      {
      nombre_actividad2: "3D en RV",
      horasdetrabajo: 40,
      fechaInicio: "11/11/24"
      },
      {
      nombre_actividad3: "RV enfocada a objetos",
      horasdetrabajo: 15,
      fechaInicio: "25/11/24"
      },
    {
    nombre_asignatura2: "Diseño 2D",
    creditos: 6,
    dificultad: "alta",
    numero_Actividades: 3,
    actividades: [
      {
      nombre_actividad1: "Animación I",
      horasdetrabajo: 14,
      fechaInicio: "20/1/24"
      },
      {
      nombre_actividad2: "Animación II",
       horasdetrabajo: 14,
      fechaInicio: "12/10/24"
      },
      {
      nombre_actividad3: "Animación III",
       horasdetrabajo: 40,
      fechaInicio: "05/12/24"
      }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

horasTotales = function (objeto) {
        
        this.objeto
        
        sumahorasTotales = proyectos.trabajos[0].PEC[0,1,2].horasdetrabajo;

        return sumahorasTotales;
        
        }
      
      console.log(horasTotales(proyectos))
```

También se me ocurrió crear una función tal como:

```
  horasTotales = function (objeto){
        
        this.objeto
        const hora1 = this.objeto.trabajos[0].actividades.[0].horasdetrabajo;
        const hora2 = this.objeto.trabajos[0].actividades.[1].horasdetrabajo;
        const hora3 = this.objeto.trabajos[0].actividades.[2].horasdetrabajo;

        sumahorasTotales = hora1 + hora2 + hora3

        return sumahorasTotales;
        
        }
      
      console.log(horasTotales(proyectos))
```

Comment: Mi gran pregunta es... ¿Por qué tienes tu función dentro del objeto?...

Comment: Porque según lo que tengo entendido es una buena práctica, hacer referencia al mismo objeto usando this., es por ello que tengo la funcion dentro del objeto. @Cris223511.dev

Comment: No veo ninguna utilidad al `this.objeto`, de todas formas estas ingresando a la función y retornando al valor de la suma.

Comment: Okay, muchas gracias @Cris223511.dev

Comment: Gracias, voy a ver como puedo mejorarlo. @padaleiana

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no se entiende del código? No me explico muy bien, por lo que, si podrías aconsejarme, te lo agradecería. Creo que de esta manera, también ayudaré al resto de usuarios. @padaleiana

Comment: No se entendía si estabas haciendo una pregunta/respuesta dentro de una pregunta (ya que el ejemplo y el código estaba "mezclado"), pero ahora que editaste la pregunta, ya se logra ver qué fue lo que intentaste.

Comment: Porque el valor mostrado en consola debería ser 75.. solo quieres las horas de la primera asignatura? debería mostrar el valor sumado de todas las actividades de todas las asignaturas?

Comment: Hola @Pipe, muy buena pregunta. Sí, el planteamiento del ejercicio consiste en lo siguiente: En la consola se debe de reflejar sólo el valor sumado de todas las horas de trabajo de las actividades, de la primera asignatura, que es “Realidad Virtual”.   Es decir; horas de trabajo de la primera actividad + horas de trabajo de la segunda actividad + horas de trabajo de la tercera actividad. = 75.

Comment: ¿Se entiende mejor? @Pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entonces la solucion sería algo asi:

```js
let proyectos = {
  numero_Proyectos: 2,
  trabajos: [
    {
      nombre_asignatura: "Realidad Virtual",
      creditos: 12,
      dificultad: "media",
      numero_Actividades: 3,
      actividades: [
        {
          nombre_actividad1: "Esperiencias Artísticas en RV",
          horasdetrabajo: 20,
          iniciodeltrabajo: "09/9/24"
        },
        {
          nombre_actividad2: "3D en RV",
          horasdetrabajo: 40,
          fechaInicio: "11/11/24"
        },
        {
          nombre_actividad3: "RV enfocada a objetos",
          horasdetrabajo: 15,
          fechaInicio: "25/11/24"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      nombre_asignatura: "Diseño 2D",
      creditos: 6,
      dificultad: "alta",
      numero_Actividades: 3,
      actividades: [{
          nombre_actividad1: "Animación I",
          horasdetrabajo: 14,
          fechaInicio: "20/1/24"
        },
        {
          nombre_actividad2: "Animación II",
          horasdetrabajo: 14,
          fechaInicio: "12/10/24"
        },
        {
          nombre_actividad3: "Animación III",
          horasdetrabajo: 40,
          fechaInicio: "05/12/24"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

//Con un reduce, sumamos las horas de trabajo de cada actividad (solo del primer trabajo)
const horasTotales = proyectos => proyectos.trabajos[0].actividades.reduce((acc, actividad) => acc + actividad.horasdetrabajo, 0);

//La anterior funcion sería equivalente a:
//function horasTotales(proyectos) {
//   return proyectos.trabajos[0].actividades.reduce(function(acc, actividad) {
//      return acc + actividad.horasdetrabajo, 0;
//   });
//}

console.log(horasTotales(proyectos))
```

Comment: Gracias @Pipe, por tu tiempo empleado, me ha sido muy útil tu primera solución. Estoy investigando más sobre la propiedad **reduce**, ya que me parece un buen método. En referencia a la segunda posible solución, me he perdido un poco, no sé si es una buena práctica utilizar un **return dos veces**.

Comment: Si, es absolutamente buena práctica, porque quizás estás malentendiendo el contexto. Como te indique en la versión ampliada de la función, `reduce` recibe una función como parámetro, la cual debe retornar algo (esa función interna del `reduce`)... y ya la función externa `horasTotales` pues retorna el resultado del reduce

Comment: Perfecto, gracias @Pipe